Should we create a canonical question answer pair on how to buy bitcoins with credit cards?
Over the years we've got quite a bit spam on how to buy bitcoins with credit cards.
I'd like to have a more permanent solution in place instead of a clutter of different questions and answers, and this coming up every now and then, e.g. Buy bitcoins with my regular AMEX (american express card)
Suggestions:
1) 
Should we have and maintain a list of services that allow such a thing in form of a canonical question and answer pair?
2) Should we close such questions as off-topic under the "product and service recommendation policy"?

The nearest we have to this (that I can easily find) is
How can I buy Bitcoin via a Credit Card or Paypal?
Problems:

The Q is horribly dated, it talks enthusiastically about MtGox and seeks answers for MtGox.
There are 28 answers. I have no idea whether the services mentioned in various answers are still useful or have gone out of business.

This question comes up so often (Can I get bitcoin with melli bank account) that it would be useful to have a canonical Q&A.
I'm very tempted to try and clean up How can I buy Bitcoin via a Credit Card or Paypal? to remove MtGox from the question and maybe superficially check some of the suggested sites in answers. 
